# Is there an rspec test for exact length of an attribute?

Tags: rspec, tdd, bdd

I'm trying to test the length of a zip code attribute to ensure its 5 characters long.  Right now I'm testing to make sure its not blank and then too short with 4 characters and too long with 6 characters.

Is there a way to test it being exactly 5 characters? So far I've found nothing online or in the rspec book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're testing a validation on an ActiveRecord model, I recommend trying out `shoulda-matchers`. It provides a bunch of useful RSpec extensions useful for Rails. You could write a simple one line spec for your zip code attribute:

```
describe Address do
  it { should ensure_length_of(:zip_code).is_equal_to(5).with_message(/invalid/) }
end
```

Answer (score 27):

There is no more `have` matcher in the latest major release of RSpec.

As of RSpec 3.1, the correct way to test this is :

`expect("Some string".length).to be(11)`

Answer (score 20):

RSpec allows this:

```
expect("this string").to have(5).characters
```

You can actually write anything instead of 'characters', it's just syntactic sugar. All that's happening is that RSpec is calling `#length` on the subject.

**However**, from your question it sounds like you actually want to test the *validation*, in which case I would folow @rossta's advice.

UPDATE:

Since RSpec 3, this is no longer part of rspec-expectations, but is available as a separate gem: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers

Answer (score 14):

Use `have_attributes` built-in matcher:

```rb
expect("90210").to have_attributes(size: 5) # passes
expect([1, 2, 3]).to have_attributes(size: 3) # passes
```

You can also [compose it with other matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-9/docs/composing-matchers) (here with `be`):

```rb
expect("abc").to have_attributes(size: (be > 2)) # passes
expect("abc").to have_attributes(size: (be > 2) & (be <= 4)) # passes
```

Answer (score 3):

Collection matchers (all matchers that assert against strings, hashes and arrays) have been abstracted out into a seperate gem, [rspec-collection_matchers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers).

In order to use these matchers add this to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
```

Or your `.gemspec` if you're working on a gem:

```
spec.add_development_dependency 'rspec-collection_matchers'
```

Then, add this to your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'rspec/collection_matchers'
```

And then you'll be able to use collection matchers in your spec:

```
require spec_helper
describe 'array' do
    subject { [1,2,3] }
    it { is_expected.to have(3).items }
    it { is_expected.to_not have(2).items }
    it { is_expected.to_not have(4).items }

    it { is_expected.to have_exactly(3).items }
    it { is_expected.to_not have_exactly(2).items }
    it { is_expected.to_not have_exactly(4).items }

    it { is_expected.to have_at_least(2).items }
    it { is_expected.to have_at_most(4).items }

    # deliberate failures
    it { is_expected.to_not have(3).items }
    it { is_expected.to have(2).items }
    it { is_expected.to have(4).items }

    it { is_expected.to_not have_exactly(3).items }
    it { is_expected.to have_exactly(2).items }
    it { is_expected.to have_exactly(4).items }

    it { is_expected.to have_at_least(4).items }
    it { is_expected.to have_at_most(2).items }
end
```

Note that you can use `items` and `characters` interchangeably, they're just syntax-sugar, and the `have` matcher, and its variants, can be used on arrays, hashes and your string.