# How to test validation of length of attribute which type is array in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a module with an attribute which data type is an array.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attribute :nicknames, Array[String]
   validates :nicknames, length: {maximum: 3}
end
```

How can test validation of quantity of nicknames of the user?
I've tried to implement

```
require 'spec_helper'
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  describe 'validation'
    it { is_expected.to validate_length_of(:nicknames).is_at_most(3) }
  end
end
```

but get the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to validate_length_of('nickname').is_at_most(3) }
   Expected User to validate that the length of
     :nicknames is at most 3, but this could not be proved.
     After setting :nicknames to
 As indicated in the message above, :nicknames seems to be changing
 certain values as they are set, and this could have something to do
 with why this test is failing. If you've overridden the writer method
 for this attribute, then you may need to change it to make this test
 pass, or do something else entirely.
```

Also have tried methods from [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113834/is-there-an-rspec-test-for-exact-length-of-an-attribute) but with no luck.
Thanks in advance and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does User need to inherit from ActiveRecord?

Comment: @aridlehoover yes. User must inherit from AR.